# In VBA, how to "if cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 1" Then

Tags: ms-access, vba

(let's start by telling I'm a real beginner in coding)

I need to check for more than one value in a combox box column field, something like:

```
If me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 1" Then

If me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 2" Then 

If me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 3" Then
```

Is there any syntax to have this on a single line of code ? or in the same expression ? like "certain value 1" or "certain value 2".

Or doesn't seems to work here.

Comment: Do you expect different results based on the certain values 1, 2, 3 or the same?

Comment: I expect the same results !

Comment: Did you try  If  me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 1"  OR  me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 2"  .OR .... then

Comment: Use line breaks so easier to read

Comment: It's working !!!! Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 2):

As can't show properly in comments use the following syntax:

```
If me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 1"  OR _
   me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 2 " OR _ 
   me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value 3 " OR _  ' Extend as appropriate
   me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value n " Then

   'Do something

End If
```

Line break `_` allows you to extend whilst still being able to read the different OR conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you may choose to use a function, which tells you whether a value is in a given array of values. Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim varArr  As Variant

    varArr = Array("test", "me", "today", "or")

    Debug.Print valueInArray("test", varArr)    'true
    Debug.Print valueInArray("test2", varArr)   'false

End Sub


Public Function valueInArray(myValue As Variant, _
                myArray As Variant, Optional isString As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim counter  As Long

    If isString Then
        myArray = Split(myArray, ":")
    End If

    For counter = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
        myArray(counter) = CStr(myArray(counter))
    Next counter

    valueInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(CStr(myValue), myArray, 0))

End Function
```

The function valueInArray tells you whether a value is present in an array. In your case, it can be used like this:

```
if valueInArray(me.cbo.Column(0), Array("certain value 1","certain value 2")) then
```